# Do I have to close a stream made with make-string-input-stream

Tags: stream, common-lisp, sbcl

The question says it all. I am wondering because the [clhs](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_s_1.htm) for `make-string-input-stream` do not specify nor does the example code show the closing. But expanding `with-input-from-string` does close the stream.

```
(with-input-from-string (stream "hallo")
  )
```

becomes

```
(LET ((#:STRING1525 "hallo"))
  (LET ((STREAM (MAKE-STRING-INPUT-STREAM #:STRING1525 0)))
    (MULTIPLE-VALUE-PROG1 (UNWIND-PROTECT (PROGN) (CLOSE STREAM)))))
```

Comment: Be careful about macro expansions, at least tell us the implementation you used.  Nothing in the standard requires that expansion, or a similar one.  An implementation could have used all internal symbols, such as opaque, non-standard special operators, or inline the body of the standard functions.

Comment: I added the implementation used in in the tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The garbage collector will take care of cleaning it up if you don't close it before reusing the variable. Since string input streams don't have any side effects, `CLOSE` doesn't perform any necessary actions.

It would be different for output streams, because closing the stream may be necessary for side effects, such as flushing the last bit of buffered output (although you could call [`FORCE-OUTPUT` or `FINISH-OUTPUT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm) yourself as well).

Comment: do it is not possible to leak stream handler by not closing the stream?

Comment: Only if you keep the stream alive be having a reference to it in a variable somewhere. It's just like any other Lisp data.

Comment: The macros does it, probably because it's nice to not be sloppy about resources. If it's a big deal one should probably keep using the `with*` macros. There are lots of questions about missing data from not properly closed output streams/file handles on this site so getting the good habit might not be a bad idea.

Comment: It's probably also because `WITH-INPUT-FROM-STRING` is implemented in terms of `WITH-OPEN-STREAM`, which needs to handle the more general case.